# Encountering issue in SimpleDateFormat parse method in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, date, datetime

I am trying to use SimpleDateFormat.parse method to parse a date string to Date object, but it is omitting "T" in the final date that is returned. I am passing this date string `2015-04-15T12:55:07.365` and I am getting `2015-04-15 12:55:07.365` in the output. However, the desired output is `2015-04-15T12:55:07.365`.

Why is "T" in the final output omitted by this line **parsedDate = sdf.parse(transDate);**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    try 
    {
        final String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS";  // example 2015-04-15T12:55:07.365
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        String transDate = "2015-04-15T12:55:07.365";
        Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(transDate);

        System.out.println("transDate:"+transDate+", parsedDate: "+parsedDate);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The output `2015-04-15 12:55:07.365` is correct, because a `Date` has a specific format in his `toString` method. It doesn't matter if you used a `SimpleDateFormat` to "create" it.

Comment: Yes, but i am asked to generate this output ==> 2015-04-15T12:55:07.365

Comment: The first comment (already deleted) already told you what you need to do, but you argued "against" it. Would will happen if you just try it? :)

Comment: I already answered it, format requires Date object and not string, and my requirement is to pass date as string and get the date object back with 'T' in it in the middle

Comment: *"get the date object back with 'T' in it in the middle"* Whoever gave you this assignment has no idea how `Date` works. A `Date` has no format, so your only way to get the "content" of the `Date` instance in a the desired format is to use `SimpleDateFormat.format(Date)`.

Answer (score 2):

You never get your desired output `2015-04-15T12:55:07.365`

**Why?**

Because you are printing Date object `parsedDate`.Date class has it's own toString() method implementation.When you are printing the date object, it means it basically prints the toString() method implementation format.

see the [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString()) for details

Comment: Yup. Mention that you can use that same pattern to produce the desired output using the `format` method (IIRC).

Comment: format method requires Date object and not string, and my requirement is to pass date as string and get the date object back with 'T' in it in the middle

Comment: @user1259618 *"and my requirement is to pass date as string and get the date object back with 'T' in it in the middle"* As I said in my above comment, whoever gave you this assignment has no idea how `Date` works. Or you misunderstand your own assignment.

Answer (score 2):

`System.out.println(parsedDate)` would give you `Wed Apr 15 00:55:07 GMT 2015` which is the toString() representation of the date object.

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse AND format dates:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date date = sdfParser.parse("2015-04-15T12:55:07.365");

SimpleDateFormat sdfFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String formattedDate = sdfFormatter.format(date);

System.out.println(formattedDate);
// 2015-04-15T12:55:07.365
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get desired output here.

```
   public static void main(String args[]) {

    {

        try {
            String transDate = "2015-04-15T12:55:07.365";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date date = sdf.parse(transDate);
            SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            Date d = sdf.parse(sdf.format(date));
            String formattedTime = output.format(d);
            System.out.println("transDate:" + transDate + ", parsedDate: " + formattedTime);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already getting 'T' in transdate, but my question is that can i get time like that in Date object 2015-04-15T12:55:07.365

Comment: You can use : Date javaUtilDate = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
                String dt = formatter.format(javaUtilDate);
                System.out.println(dt);